# Перенос данных между двумя UIViewController

Tags: swift, swift4, uiviewcontroller

Возникла такая проблема которую не могу решить. У меня на первом ViewController стоит TextView и кнопка. При нажатии написанный текст трансформируется и должен быть отображен на другом ViewController в другом TextView. Все работает если эти TextView находятся на одной странице, но не работает если на разных.
Заранее спасибо за Ваши ответы.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что вам просто надо перенести данные с одного ViewConrolller на другой?

Comment: @Olter да. написанный текст на одном ViewController при нажатии кнопки должен быть трансформирован на другом ViewController

Comment: На самом деле хороший вопрос, пусть и новичковый. Задача очень часто встречается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я немного обобщу ответ, т.к. у вас вопрос в общем-то заключается в том, как правильно перенести данные с одного ViewController на другой.

Наиболее правильный способ решения такой:

Пусть у вас есть два ViewController A и В.
На A у вас есть textFieldA.

При переходе на ViewControllerB вам надо передать туда текст textFieldA.
Для этого создаете в ViewControllerB свойство для этих данных.

```
class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {
//  Свойства класса
var passedStringFromVCA: String?
// Конструкторы, методы и.т.п
}
```

На ViewControllerA перегружаете метод prepareForSegue.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "toVCB") {
            let destinationVC: ViewControllerB = segue.destination as! ViewControllerB;
            destinationVC.passedStringFromVCA = textFieldA.text
    }
```

Ну и допустим, вы переходите на B по нажатию на какую-то кнопку.

```
@IBAction func moveToBButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toVCB", sender: sender)
    }
```

На сториборде у вас соотвественно должен быть этот сегвэй с id="toVCB"

Ну и преобразование для textFieldB делаете уже где хотите. Например в `viewDidLoad` у ViewControllerB.

В принципе есть еще способы передать данные, но этот вариант на мой взгляд наиболее простой и правильный.

Comment: А куда вписывать IBAction для второго textview? а то в коде выдает "Use of unresolved identifier". Я просто как раз новичек и пытаюсь разобраться

Comment: Ммм, зачем вам action для textview? Вы с первого контроллера передали стрингу во второй. Теперь, во втором контроллере во viewDidLoad пишите `self.textViewB.text = passedStringFromVCA;` Если видите свое переданное значение, значит все правильно, можете писать преобразование. Если нет - где-то ошиблись, ищите где.

Comment: "Use of unresolved identifier" на что выдает-то? Вы в viewControllerA используете объект класса viewControllerB, у вас А про В знает? Если нет, надо дописать `import viewControllerB.h` в viewControllerA

Comment: На аутлеты двух textview выдает, которые находятся во viewControllerB. Например `transformedTextView.text = transform(textView.text)`

Comment: Еще раз. Вы не передаете textview. Вы передаете текст с него, это тип String. В примере выше это свойство passedStringFromVCA. Вам не надо передавать объект класса, вы же в transform собрались использовать только строку, а не сам объект. transform(passedStringFromVCA) должно быть. Нет, объекты тоже можно передавать между контролерами, но это сложнее, и, как мне кажется, в вашем случае не требуется.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде я все понял. Только вот `import viewControllerB.h` не воспринимает

Comment: Не надо там импорта, скорее всего контроллеры друг друга видят, я просто не понял сначала в каком месте у вас сообщение об ошибке, поэтому про импорт написал. P.S. Если ответ вам помог, отметьте его как принятый пожалуйста.

Comment: Вроде получилось, но почему то вторая страница пролистывается два раза

Comment: Segue как добавляли? Если вы сначала сделали его через IB (правый клик с кнопки на второй контроллер), а потом еще программно (как я написал), то получится переход два раза .