# У меня никак не выходит передача данных между ViewController's

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile-development, apple

Я создаю новый viewController, меняю в нём значение переменной, но когда возвращаюсь к ней, там остаётся значение выставленное по умолчанию.

Когда я создаю Storyboard прошлого окна (куда я заново потом перейду), я не могу присвоить и забрать данные из Label Я должен буду забрать значение из Label другого окна, сложить с TextField в открытом окне, присвоить Label из прошлого окна и перейти dismiss-ом обратно к Label

```
class BudgetVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var budgetText: UILabel!
var budgetTextValue: String? = "0"

@IBAction func consumptionButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

}

@IBAction func incomeButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

}

//    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
//        if (segue.identifier == "toVCB")
//        {
//        // Get reference to the destination view controller
//        let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Consumption") as! ConsumptionVC
//
//        // Pass any objects to the view controller here
//        vc.callback = { result in
//            self.budgetTextValue = String(result) // этот detail потом подстваляете в методе cellForRowAtIndexPath
//        }
//    }
//    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    budgetText.text = budgetTextValue
    print(budgetTextValue)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    budgetText.text = budgetTextValue
    print(budgetTextValue)
}
}

    class ConsumptionVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textNumberBudget: UITextField!
//    var callback : ((Int)->())?

    @IBAction func addNumberToBudgetPressed(_ sender: Any) {
//        guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Budget") as? BudgetVC else { return }
//        var budgetTextInt = Int(textNumberBudget.text!)!
//        self.callback?(budgetTextInt)
//
//        budgetTextInt += Int(vc.budgetTextValue!)!
//        vc.budgetTextValue? = String(budgetTextInt)
//
//        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toVCB", sender: sender)
//        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "toVCB")
        {
            let destinationVC : BudgetVC = segue.destination as! BudgetVC
            var budgetTextInt = Int(textNumberBudget.text!)!
            budgetTextInt += Int(destinationVC.budgetText.text!)!//Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
            destinationVC.budgetTextValue = String(budgetTextInt)
        }
    }
```

[image: Storyboard]

Хотел, что бы в итоге значение изменилось. Извините за, наверняка, глупый вопрос. Я учусь и отлично отношусь к критике. Буду рад, если предложите какую-нибудь информацию, рад поучиться, заранее спасибо

Comment: Я запутался, если честно. Во-первых, я вижу, что вы не используете UINavigationController. Навигацию между контролерами _можно_ делать без него, но _намного_ удобнее с ним. Сразу избавитесь от всяких `instantiateViewController` и `self.dismiss`. Если от UINavigationController вы отказались осознанно, то напишите об этом прямо. По текущему коду, я не знаю, что у вас на storyboard, но по ощущению вы каждый раз создаете новый экзепляр контроллера (который естественно с default-значениями)

Comment: Посмотрите вот эти вопросы: [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/981281/Передача-состояния-между-viewcontrollers/981356#981356) и [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/958053/Перенос-данных-между-двумя-uiviewcontroller/958077#958077)

Comment: Прошу прощения, отредактировал вопрос, начинаю двигаться в Swift, не знал об этом, спасибо за ссылки, буду рад, если укажите на ошибки @Olter

Comment: Я прочел и опробовал ресурсы, но я всё равно создаю новый экземпляр контроллера, я был бы очень признателен, если ты подскажешь как этого избежать @Olter

Comment: Для начала я бы все-таки посоветовал использовать NavigationViewController. Он создается достаточно просто: допустим у вас сейчас на storyboard есть два ViewController, выбираете первый, в меню выбираете _editor->embed in->navigation controller_.  Далее, допустим у вас есть на этом контроллере кнопка, по нажатию на которую вы хотите переходить на второй. **Правой кнопкой мыши** делаете drag&drop с кнопки на второй контроллер. Выбираете _show_. Это будет _segue_. Проверяете, что переход вперед и назад работает корректно. Потом читаете два моих ответа по ссылкам выше и думаете, как это применить

Comment: @Olter у меня сложилось впечатление, что переходы между окнами кодом надёжнее, чем так, ибо ты можешь задать какое-либо условие перехода и так далее, разве нет?

Comment: Segue точно так же можно делать программно, можно ставить условия и.т.п. Navigation Controller дает вам верхнюю панель, которая а) стандарт для iOS б) достаточна удобна по умолчанию. В противном случае вам придется рисовать эту панель самостоятельно (что сложно), либо обходиться без нее (что очень непривычно для пользователя т.к см пункт а)

Comment: Я вам просто привел самый простой пример, как сделать segue даже без программного вызова. Никто не запрещает вам в коде нажатия на кнопку вызвать `performSegueWithIdentifier` при каком-то условии

Comment: @Olter Я всё переделал под каждую из ссылок, но всё равно у меня никак не выходит поменять значение на BudgetVC ни через prepare, ни через calback, может я в другом месте ошибся, он всё равно вызывает новый ViewController

Comment: Обновите код вопроса тогда. storyboard.instantiateViewController убрали из кода надеюсь?

Comment: @Olter Да, конечно, пару минут

Comment: @Olter Всё готово

Comment: Я написал ответ. Судя по вашему скриншоту, вы замкнули навигацию на себя, не надо так. Второй segue (от контроллера с add до черного) лишний. При этом на втором контроллере вы должны видеть кнопку 'назад'

Comment: Ответ мне помог и решил мою проблему, надеюсь он решит не только мою проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так, если я правильно понял вашу задачу, у вас должно было получиться примерно вот так:

Первый контроллер (у вас это, как я понял, с кнопками + и -)

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    // У вас вместо textfield label, но не суть важно
    @IBOutlet weak var textfieldTop: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func buttonBottomTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "second", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        let vc: SecondViewController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here
        vc.callback = { result in
            // Вот тут делаете все что вам надо с результатом: складываете/вычитаете/преобразуете и.т.п Для примера я просто занес его в другой textfield
            self.textfieldTop.text = result
        }
    }
}
```

Второй контроллер:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldTop: UITextField!
    var callback : ((String)->())?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.callback?(textFieldTop.text ?? "")
    }

    @IBAction func ButtonAddTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // по нажатии на кнопку переходим назад. Полностью аналогично кнопке 'назад' в верхней панели navigationViewcontroller
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

В данном конкретном примере segue создавался между ViewController-ами. Т.е выбрали ViewController на vc, сделали drag&drop с него на второй и прописали идентификатор "second". Можно сделать сразу segue с кнопки из Interface Builder, как я писал в комментариях, тогда метод `buttonBottomTapped` не нужен.

На Storyboard должно получиться примерно так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 'Конроллер' аж два раза, тьфу. 'Контроллер' конечно же. ¯|_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Огромное спасибо, я очень много думал над этой проблемой теперь буду анализировать код :D Есть одно уточнение в строчке перехода         'self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "second", sender: self)' Код вызывает её второй раз, можно ли как-то отменить её действие не в коде, дабы переход вызывался единожды?

Comment: Второй раз он у вас вызывается из-за того, что вы его сначала в Interface Builder сделали. Я вам написал об этом. Чтобы убрать второй вызов либо удалите метод 'buttonBottomTapped', либо удалите segue в Storyboard между кнопкой и контроллером. (если хотите вызывать программно через 'performSegue', то в Storyboard должны быть связаны контроллеры, а не контроллер и кнопка) В общем, почитайте подробней, как именно работает segue.